# Integrating Bootstrap admin panel into website, what are my options?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system

I've been developing websites for clients for a number of years, mostly static HTML sites, and some clients needed things like ecommerce so I went with WordPress and Drupal. Recently, however, I've decided that I want to be able to give my clients a more professional looking package when it comes to the CMS sites, so I want to step away from things like WordPress.

I've found several very nice Bootstrap Admin Themes that I am going to take inspiration from, and designing the admin panels isn't going to be a problem. What I need to know is, what sort of back end is needed for using a custom admin panel with a website? Can I simply make the panel and program a few CRUD methods into it? Or are there CMS options out there that will allow me to integrate these admin panels into them?

Sorry if this is off topic, but I've googled and searched this page countless times for this answer and can find no good information on it anywhere! There are so many templates I'm assuming someone is using them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not replying with an answer to your specific questions more an alternative.

Have you considered custom Admin panels in wordpress - like these - https://codecanyon.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=WordPress+Admin

Just an idea.

Comment: While this is definitely a step in the right direction, and I may use this for a few clients who still require a full blown CMS like WordPress (thank you!), I still would rather be able to use my own admin panels, as it lets me customise them completely. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with ready to use bootstrap admin templates as you will get many admin templates with backend integration. It will save your time and money too on the development process. With bootstrap admin templates you will get ready-made UI design that you can change as per your requirements. If you want to do any customization on admin templates, then it is easy to do so.
You can also consider this resource with good options for [Backend admin panel templates](https://themeselection.com/backend-admin-panel-template-free-download/) for your website.